# Chrome.... Search bar shrinks

Tags: css, google-chrome

This is weird.

http://elektrikhost.com

On page load, or the index page the search bar shrinks. Click about-us and it grows back. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, it looks like a character is inserted at the top of the document, before the doctype, in the index page, which prevents the doctype from being parsed. This might explain the current behavior.

Comment: Yup I was using php include to put in the html, I guess I can't do that with the doctype.